# Calculate an average every 15 seconds

Tags: matlab

I have a time row with a matrix of *1 **x** 14401* first I put in the command:

```
data.time2(1,2) - data.time2(1,1)
```

which produced `2.8935e-06` which is the time step between each point (I was told this is in days). First I need to convert this into seconds but I am not sure of the commands and then average every 15 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% convert to seconds
seconds = data.time2 * 24 * 60 * 60;
```

Since step between points is `0.25` seconds, you should average 60 points in a row.

```
% mask for averaging every 60 points
W = 60;
mask = ones(1,W) / W;

% calculating averages, length will be: 14401 - 60 + 1 = 14342
averages = conv( seconds, mask, 'valid' );
```

Comment: I believe you can use averages = conv( seconds, mask, 'same') to get similar behavior, and not have to manually extract the parts you want.

Comment: @Pete, I've looked it up in [`conv` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/conv.html). My code could indeed be shortened, but by using `'valid'` as a third argument. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: You're right; valid does what you want.  "same" gives the original data size back, which is typically what I want, but probably not right for this application.